# Select column data depending on another column data

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table 'measure' in a PostgreSQL database.

```
id   | value | id_sensor  
-----+-------+----------
1    | 1.24  | 1     
2    | 1.56  | 1     
3    | 1.21  | 2     
4    | 1.89  | 3     
5    | 1.42  | 3
```

I am looking for a `SELECT` query that will return values of each sensors.
Notice That the isn't the same number of rows on each sensor_id. (put a Nan if not exist)

The assert of this query is:

```
1.24 | 1.21 | 1.89  
1.56 | Nan  | 1.42
```

I try a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT id_sensor FROM measure GROUP BY id_sensor)
FROM measure
GROUP BY id_sensor
```

but it return this error:

> ERROR: ERREUR:  plus d'une ligne renvoyée par une sous-requête utilisée comme une expression
> *Traduction* ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

I have not a fixed number of sensor. The query has to be able to gather n sensors (Else it will be a duplicated question).

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select max(value) filter (where id_sensor = 1) as sensor_1,
       max(value) filter (where id_sensor = 2) as sensor_2,
       max(value) filter (where id_sensor = 3) as sensor_3
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_sensor order by id) as seqnum
      from measures m
     ) m
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Hi, I have various number of sensor.

Comment: @VincentBénet . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Yes, I need an answer without dependancy of the number of sensors.
Accepting this was a mistake because it don t answer 100 % the problem. But it helps me a lot, thank you.

Comment: If you modify your answer with this condition it is ok for me to accept

Comment: @VincentBénet . . . That is not the question asked here.  To solve that problem, you need dynamic SQL which is considerably more complicated.

Comment: This is the question asked here. (look at the end of the question). I am really grateful for your answer, it helps but it was not what I wanted at 100 %

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(value) filter(where id_sensor = 1) sensor1,
    max(value) filter(where id_sensor = 2) sensor2,
    max(value) filter(where id_sensor = 3) sensor3
from (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by id_sensor order by id) rn
    from measure m
) m
group by rn
```

Comment: Hi, as mentionned into the edited version, I have n sensors into the database

Comment: @VincentBénet: a SQL query returns a fixed set of columns. You can add more conditional expressions to the `SELECT` clause to handle more possible sensors (where there is no data, you get a `NULL` value). If you want something that adapts the number of columns to your data, then you need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.

Comment: Okay, could you tell me more about Dynamic SQL in that case please ?